# Sound issues with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I recently replaced my Windows 7 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Everything works great except that I'm unable to play sound through my headphones. It worked well in Windows but now it won't.

[image: Here is a screenshot of my system sound settings]

I have tested sound for both the options but can't get it running. I have also tried **sudo alsa force-reload** but to no avail. I'm relatively new to Ubuntu and am really troubled by this. Any help on this would be really appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Connected via analog jack

My soundcard details are:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 81a7 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 40 Memory at d20c0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K] Capabilities: <access denied> Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

Comment: Headphones will appear in sound settings when plugged into the headphone jack, and only then (on recognizing something was plugged in there we will change to headphone profile). Also make sure they are not muted by running `alsamixer` in a terminal.

Comment: Don't mess with ALSA. Install PulseAudio Volume Control (pavucontrol in the repositories) and have a look at that.

Comment: You may find this useful: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting#Sound_Output_Troubleshooting.  Please add further information to your question such as how your headphones are connected to your system. Analog, USB, Bluetooth? Please help us help you by narrowing down the possible sources of the problem. All I know about your headphones at the moment is that they are yours.

Comment: @ElderGeek they are connected by a jack(analog). My soundcard details are:
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 81a7
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 40
 Memory at d20c0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yoour Sound settings image indicates that you have it set to use the digital S/PDIF connection. Change it and choose analog.

If your headphones have a Microphone attached, you will have 2 jacks, one input (pink) and one output (green). Open sound settings and plug in to the matching color starting with the output jack. You should get a headphones option to choose in the sound settings that looks like this:

[image: SoundSettingsHeadphones]

The wires in these cables are very thin and flimsy. If you have an intermittant short in the wire or a poor connection you may find by wiggling it that the Headphones option appears and disappears from the Output tab.

Switching to the input tab allows for setting up the microphone (if present and attached).

Comment: My headphones do not have a microphone attached. I connect them via the green jack but the system doesn't detect the headphones.

Comment: Edited answer...

Comment: Thanks a lot @ElderGeek for your help. Was actually an issue with my headphones only. Just replaced them and everything works like a charm. Thanks for bearing with me :)

Comment: @VarunSharma Glad to help and I'm happy you got it sorted out.